# How to remove first 3 posts on an archive page?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, wordpress-theming

I am new to theme development and coding one theme from scratch, I have to build archive page where it will not show/ exclude first 3 posts. I tried below codes but it's showing same post on all the category archive page. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

```html
<div class="row">
    <?php
    query_posts('posts_per_page=6&offset=3');
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    ?>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID) ?>" class="archive-title"><?php the_title()?></a></h2>
      <div class="py-2"><span class="text-gray">By</span> <strong><a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $post->post_author); ?>"><?php the_author()?></a></strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="text-gray"><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?>&middot;&nbsp;<?php echo reading_time(); ?></span></div>
      <div class="py-2"><?php the_excerpt()?></div>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

For this, you want to use the hook `pre_get_posts`

You can add this to your functions.php of your theme/child theme.  You should remove what you have written.

```
query_posts('posts_per_page=6&offset=3')
```

This will change all archive pages to have an offset of 3.  You can modify the condition as needed to only update specific archives.

```php
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'dd_offset_archive_posts');
function dd_offset_archive_posts($query){
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_archive()){
        $query->set('offset', 3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately I can't add this in functions.php as I have to create something like '3 recent posts in one row, description in one row, recent posts starting from 4th in one row', can u help?

Comment: That seems like a different question entirely.  Is this for a specific page template, or an archive?

Comment: It's archive page, https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6xBx.png

Comment: From your mockup, it is still unclear what you want.  Certainly, from what your code is, you wouldn't get there.  Can you refine your mockup?  It doesn't follow from what you've titled the post. I mean, you asked how to remove the first three posts.  The answer shows you how to exclude the first three posts.  What you're asking is really something more along the lines of "I am making a custom archive with the following requirements" which those are still unclear.  It seems to me you need to make an incremented loop with variable headings?